# Can a hulking hurler use both its two-handed hurl tricks with one attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class

The prestige class hulking hurler at levels 2 and 3 gains the extraordinary ability **two-handed hurl trick** that, in part, says that he "chooses one of the following tricks. In order to use any of these abilities, the hulking hurler must grip the weapon or improvised weapon in two hands and throw it as a full-round action" (*Complete Warrior* 41). This is followed by a list of five tricks from which a hurler can pick.

Can a Large level 3 hulking hurler that picks the two-handed hurl tricks area attack and overburdened heave use these two tricks simultaneously to take a full-round action to throw a Huge weapon at an area? Or must this typical Large hurler somehow increase its size category to Huge (so that he can employ a two-handed thrown weapon designed for a Huge creature) to use the two-handed hurl trick area attack?

Similarly, can the two-handed hurl tricks meteor strike and power attack be used simultaneously on one massive attack? Or must the hurler pick when he makes the attack *either* the trick meteor strike *or* the trick power attack?

Comment: I was including these abilities in an answer to another of your questions, hadn't seen this question yet.  The anomalous text for Meteor Strike (not fixed in the errata) makes it unclear...

Comment: @KerrAvon2055  I saw that. Thank you. What about the text of the trick meteor strike is anomalous? The whole Huge weapon thing?

Comment: The anomalous bit is that in the discussion of all the tricks it says "In order to use any of these abilities … and throw it as a full round action."  Then the individual description for Meteor Strike only starts "As a full round action..."  If this is intentional rather than sloppy wording, it means that Meteor Strike alone is a full round action, so you would not be able to also use the trick power attack in combination.  Otherwise there seems no reason for the thrower not to be able to combine their tricks into one attack.

Comment: Is there any reason why an attack cannot be delayed for two rounds in order to stack the effects, assuming that said wording was intentional?

Answer (score 1):

> **Two-Handed Hurl Trick (Ex)**: At 2nd level and again at 3rd level, a
>   hulking hurler chooses **one** of the following tricks. In order to use
>   any of these abilities, the hulking hurler must grip the weapon or
>   improvised weapon in two hands and throw it as **a full-round action**.

The Two-Handed Hurl Trick is a full round action, and thus cannot be used in combination with any other standard, move or full round actions.
It also specifically says you choose one for the action.

Comment: RE: "It also specifically says you choose one for the action." Where? I mean, I see the emphasized part that says the weapon must be gripped in two hands and thrown as a full-round action, but which two-handed hurl tricks the creature possesses because of levels in the class doesn't seem to (*ahem*) impact whether or not tricks can be combined.

Comment: I argue because the wording states you are choosing individual tricks, and names them as abilities rather than naming Hurl Trick as an ability and the below list as effects of that ability.